# Access amqp_URI from spring boot application.properties file

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, application.properties

I have amqp_URI like below

```
amqp://sds:%23%23%45%56%65%56%56%@myserver:5672
```

I need access to this server from Spring boot `application.properties` file. I have tried `spring.rabbitmq.addresses` property .But no luck.

any heads up would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below properties in application.properties -

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=
spring.rabbitmq.virtual-host= <if you are using root (/) remove this property>
spring.rabbitmq.port=
spring.rabbitmq.username=
spring.rabbitmq.password=
```

To listen a queue (e.g: test-queue) you can use below code -

```
@Component
public class TestConsumer {
    @RabbitListener(queues = 'test-queue')
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
      //TODO
    }
}
```